# CSS Align Small Div Blocks

Tags: html, css, alignment

So basically I made these blocks out of div,
this is my HTML:

```
    <div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #FF6947;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #9400DE;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #16B5C9;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #0B399C;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #E3426A;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #ED1313;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #52E342;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #1BA30B;"></div>
    </div>
```

Then my CSS goes like this:

```
.cp{
    /* these styles will let the divs line up next to each other
       while accepting dimensions */
    display: block;
    float: left;

    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;

    /* a small margin to separate the blocks */
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I have tried a lot of margin alignment tactics and other stuff to get each row of blocks to align to center, though I just cannot get my head around it. Can anybody figure this out? I really appreciate it.

Comment: YES! Thank you for all your solutions, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to give class (or another identifier) to the container (like `.container`) and change inner content's layout to inline so it can be centered with `text-align: center`:

```
 .container { text-align:center; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5xSY/)

Another option is to use table layout (`display: table` applies to the `.container` and `display: table-cell` to the inner content). Then you can easily center `.container` with `margin: 0 auto`.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5xSY/2/)

Answer (score 0):

- Don't float the blocks
- make them display: inline-block
- text-align: center the parent

http://jsfiddle.net/9Akaw/

```
#parent {
    text-align: center;
}
.cp {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
}


<div id="parent">
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #FF6947;"></div>
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #9400DE;"></div>
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #16B5C9;"></div>
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #0B399C;"></div>
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #E3426A;"></div>
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #ED1313;"></div>
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #52E342;"></div>
  <div class="cp" style="background-color: #1BA30B;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/Z92TQ/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #FF6947;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #9400DE;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #16B5C9;"></div>
    <div class="cp" style="background-color: #0B399C;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

.cp {
    /* these styles will let the divs line up next to each other
       while accepting dimensions  float: left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
    /* a small margin to separate the blocks */
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```